# Add string to prefix of form text

Tags: php, javascript, forms

I am trying to store Web addresses and I need the prefix to be "http://" so if the visitor doesn't type that in I need to add it but if they do type it in I don't want to duplicate it. This question has to have been asked before. Maybe I'm not searching correctly? Either way, if you can answer this you are the kind of person I aspire to be.

I would like to do this in PHP but JS would be ok too.

edit:
This is what I tried to add JS to but didn't work...

```
 <form name="urlField" onsubmit="window.location.href = document.getElementById('addressfield').value; return false;">
   <input type="text" name="address" id="addressfield" />
 </form>
```

Here is the PHP on the receiving end of the one that posts data:

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['success']) === true && empty($_GET['success']) === true) {
    echo '<img src="images/spacer.gif" border="0" width="270" height="1">Your links have been updated!';
} else {
if (empty($_POST) === false && empty($errors) === true) {   
    $update_data = array(
        'a1_url'    => $_POST['a1_url'],
        'a1_text'   => $_POST['a1_text'],
    );
    update_user($session_user_id, $update_data);
    header('Location: ../edit_mode.php');
    exit();
    } else if (empty($errors) === false) {
        echo output_errors($errors);
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a simple regex that checks if a protocol for the URL has been specified:

```
if (!preg_match('#^[a-zA-Z]+://#', $url)) {
    //No current protocol - add http
    $url = 'http://' . $url;
}
```

or in JS:

```
if (!url.match(/^[a-zA-Z]+:\/\//)) {
    url = 'http://' + url;
}
```

This would allow `ssh://localhost`, `https://www.facebook.com`, `ftp://mydomain.com` etc.

**Regex explanation:**

- `^` - the start of the string must be here
- `[a-zA-Z]+` - the letters from a to z, both upper and lower case repeated 1 or more times
- `:` - a litteral `:` character
- `\/\/` or `//` - The litteral `//` characters, but escaped in javascript using backslash.

**Update to your comment**:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function submitURLFieldForm() {
        var url = document.getElementById('addressfield').value;
        if (!url.match(/^[a-zA-Z]+:\/\//)) {
            url = 'http://' + url;
        }

        window.location.href = url; 
        return false;
    }
</script>
<form name="urlField" onsubmit="return submitURLFieldForm();"> URL<input type="text" name="address" /></form>
```

Comment: Of all the answers this is the one I've focused on for some reason. Now I will expose even a deeper level of ignorance - how might I incorporate that into my form? I have tried the simplest way I can think: to add your JS example as an onMouseOut event but to no avail.\

Comment: @LyleCrumbstorm Simply switch `$url` out with eg. `$_POST['url']` instead (if you're using `POST` to submit the form, and `url` is the name of the input field.

Comment: I don't know how this is going to go over - me changing the "Accepted Answer" but @duellsy pointed me in the right direction and this one cleaned it up. Together I got a solution that solves my problem. I love this Website.

Comment: Can you please show me how to incorporate the JS version into the following: `<form name="urlField" onsubmit="window.location.href = document.getElementById('addressfield').value; return false;">
  URL<input type="text" name="address" /></form>` I've tried jerry rigging this in every way but the logic escapes me.

Comment: @LyleCrumbstorm Check out my edit - it should explain it to you. Here I change it to pointing to a function instead (you can actually indent it, and it's easier to read).

Comment: That's poetry. Thank you for knowing your stuff!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var inputVal = $('#myInput').val();
inputVal = inputVal.substr(0, 8).search(/(http|https)(:\/\/)/,i) === 0
           ? 'http://' + inputVal
           : inputVal;
```

(added support for HTTPS and case-insensitive)

Comment: Have you tested it? `http|https` should be rewritten as `https?`.

Comment: Yep, works for both cases. Enter in console `'http://x.com'.substr(0, 8).search(/(http|https)(:\/\/)/,i) === 0` or `'https://x.com'.substr(0, 8).search(/(http|https)(:\/\/)/,i) === 0` or `'x.com'.substr(0, 8).search(/(http|https)(:\/\/)/,i) === 0`

Comment: wouldn't `https?` be easier than `http|https`?

Comment: Between this & h2oo...'s reply I'm going to get this working. Here's another layer I did not mention. I have 2 places for URL's to be entered: 1 is w/in JS that simply passes the string to the window.location.href and the other puts it into a database. Using your example, I suspect this needs to go into the script that receives the post data from the form - ? If so, where? (I am so ashamed to be asking questions like this.)

Comment: Sorry for not being sharp enough to figure this out on my own (and I've tried!) but how would I incorporate this into my current code?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way (**JavaScript** solution):

```
var visitorTyped = "example.com";
if (visitorTyped.indexOf("http://") === -1) {
   visitorTyped = "http://" + visitorTyped
}
```

Comment: Which is fine, if JavaScript is enabled. Doing a server-side check would also be worthwhile.

Answer (score 0):

Since you requested you preferred PHP:

Create a new variable to hold the url, and do your checking on that. You can then assign this new variable to the a1_url item in your `update_data` array to store

```
if (empty($_POST) === false && empty($errors) === true) {   

  $url = $_POST['a1_url'];
  if (strpos($url, 'http://') !== 0) {
    $url = 'http://' . $url
  }

  $update_data = array(
      'a1_url'    => $url,
      'a1_text'   => $_POST['a1_text'],
  );

  // the remainder of your code
}
```

Comment: whoa! 3 answers before I could refresh my browser! it's 2:12 a.m. here in CO. it will be after some sleep before I get to thank someone. :)

Comment: it's only 6:15pm where I am ;)

Comment: I'm so sorry for being so dense but where do I put that in order for it to work? Did I mention that I'm brand new to PHP? Learning fast but things are coming at me faster!

Comment: updated my answer to show where to put this, note the new $url variable being used.

Comment: I have added that but it still does not add "http://" to the beginning when it posts to the database. No matter what I put in the field THAT'S what gets saved. ? Can you see anything else here that might be interfering? `<input name="a1_url" type="text" class="default-value" value="<?php echo $user_data['a1_url']; ?>" maxlength="1024">` With your addition it is still posting to the DB just not adding "http://"

Comment: And a thousand angels erupted into perfect harmony! Thank you! What was your typo?

Comment: I wasn't setting the $url value inside the if statement correctly, so it never got updated... oops!

Comment: whoa, speed bump... I just realized that if someone types in "https://" it adds an "http://" to the beginning of it.

Comment: why can't I just add `if (strpos ($url, 'http://' || 'https://') !==0)` and make this work?! I think I've tried every variation of paranthesis too but it's not happening. ?

Comment: @LyleCrumbstorm - For future referece, you'd need to `if (strpos($url, 'http://') !== 0 || strpos($url, 'https://') !== 0) {`.

Comment: well, I can say I didn't try *that* variation of paranthesis. did you see my question above about incorporating this into my current JS? I got the PHP working!

Comment: You should be doing an &&, not an || if you want to check that neither exist.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you allow for the possibility of, at least https, potentially any other protocol?

To preserve any protocol:

```
if (strpos($input, '://') === false) {
  $input = 'http://' . $input
}
```

To allow only a subset of all protocol, defaulting to http

```
$allowedProtocol = array ( 'http', 'https' );
$urlParts = explode( '://', $input );
if (count($urlParts) === 1) {
    $input = 'http://' . $input
}elseif ( !in_array( $urlParts[0], $allowedProtocol ) ) {
    // error handling
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use native PHP function:

> $url = (parse_url($url, PHP_URL_SCHEME) == NULL ? 'http://' : NULL ). $url;